# Global Variable Jquery

Tags: jquery

I've asked this question before but never actually got it working.

More or less, I have multiple JS files, that I need to check against the one variable. I have a function that checks to see if a class exists and then changes the variable.

```
var states = function(){

    if($('#Animation.switch.switchOff').length == 1){
        animationtoggle = 0;
    }
    else {
        animationToggle = 1 ;
    }
    if($('#Autoscroll.switch.switchOff').length == 1){
        scrolltoggle = 1;   
    }
    else {
        scrolltoggle = 0    
    }
    return {
        animationtoggle: animationtoggle,
        scrolltoggle: scrolltoggle
    };
}
```

I then have inside another function, in another JS file this:

```
Okay, I've done this, although It still doesn't fix my problem of being able to use this variable on another file, I have this inside the function: 

$(function() {
    var ss = states();
    ss.animationtoggle;
    var last_position = 0;
    var duration = 300;
    if (animationtoggle == 1){
       //only do something if it's equal to 1 "on"
});
```

And this is the toggle button code:

```
$('#optionMenu ul li').click(       
function() {
$(this).toggleClass('switchOff');
var ss = states();
ss.scrolltoggle;
ss.animationtoggle; 
});
```

Am I approaching this the right way?

Please help! Here's my site, the toggle is up the right hand corner at the moment :http://shannonhochkins.v5.cloudsvr.com.au/

Comment: Which is the variable in question that you want to be globally accessible? Cool site btw.

Comment: both scrolltoggle and animationtoggle @Jeemusu

Comment: so what is your problem , your variables not changing correctly , actually you have declared   var animationtoggle = 1, if you want it to be global declare it  -> animationtoggle = 1,

Comment: As everyone has said, just move the variables out of the function to the top, then when you want to use them just call the variable name. http://jsfiddle.net/wnxjz/2/

Comment: @Jeemusu, Still no luck, I've got it working on the same JS file, but on others the variable changes don't work, I am using the same queeries, but it's not working!

Comment: In that case make sure you declare them at the very top of your document, in the header, directly before any other scripts. http://jsfiddle.net/wnxjz/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are overwriting them by creating and assigning the same variable multiple times.  The global variables should be defined once outside the scope of your specific function, preferably close to the first operation on page load.  Global variables are assigned to the window object and can be accessed by name once declared.

```
//You need to define your global variable out of the scope of your function
var ss = states();

$(function() {
if (ss.animationtoggle == 1){
   //only do something if it's equal to 1 "on"
});

$('#optionMenu ul li').click(       
function() {
$(this).toggleClass('switchOff');
//Don't create the same variable here with the same name
//Instead access the global variables by using them
// ss.scrolltoggle;
// ss.animationtoggle; 
});
```

Comment: Still no luck, I've got it working on the same JS file, but on others the variable changes don't work, I am using the same queeries, but it's not working!

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
var animationtoggle = 1,
```

to

```
animationtoggle = 1,
```

and move them out of the function . if not they will be initialized again and again

Answer (score 0):

try renaming the variables in the function to avoid confusion:

```
var animationtoggle = 1;
...
```

to

```
var _animationtoggle = 1;
...
return { animationtoggle : _animationtoggle, ....}
```

or instead of your function as follows:

```
return {
        animationtoggle: ($('#Animation.switch.switchOff').length == 1)?0:1,
        scrolltoggle: ($('#Autoscroll.switch.switchOff').length == 1)?1:0
};
```